# Regex to match string delimited with two types of delimiter

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I don't really understand how regex expressions are put together, so here's my question.

I have a delimited string as `1,3;5,1;6,4` and so on. Basically what I have here is storing a shopping cart with products *IDs* and *volumes*. `1`,`3` would mean I have a product with id `"1"` and the quantity `3`. Products (with volumes) are delimited with `";"`.

What I need to do is put together a regex that will validate such string. Only positive numbers are allowed with limitation let's say from 1 to 10000.

Does anyone has a solution to that?

Comment: Let's say what have you tried?

Comment: Welcome, as you see you will not have much luck asking for outright solutions to problems which have not been attempted. What you should do is attempt it on your own, when you come to a stumbling point that can be articulated in a specific question, return and you'll likely get plenty of help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex pattern matches on semicolon-delimited number pairs, where a comma separates the members of each pair, and each number is between 1 and 10000:

```
^([1-9]\d{0,3}|10000),([1-9]\d{0,3}|10000)(;([1-9]\d{0,3}|10000),([1-9]\d{0,3}|10000))*$
```

There must be at least one pair. If there is only one pair, no semicolon follows it. Semicolons should be present only between neighboring pairs.

Answer (score 3):

I think you'd be better not using a Regex for this. Assuming that your format is like `1,3;5,1;6,4` (i.e. *not* as you've specified in your question as other @Rich points out) you should just be able to split it on `;` and then `,`:

```
var input = "1,3;5,1;6,4";

var pairs = input.Split(';')                        // ["1,3","5,1","6,4"]
    .Select(x => x.Split(','))                      // [["1","3"],["5","1"],["6","4"]]
    .Select(x => new { Id = x[0], Volume = x[1] }); // [{ Id : "1", Volume : "3"} ...]

foreach(var pair in pairs)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Id: " + pair.Id + " Volume: " + pair.Volume);
}
// Id: 1 Volume: 3
// Id: 5 Volume: 1
// Id: 6 Volume: 4
```

Note: I've used `System.Linq` and an anonymous type here, but you could do without if you prefer.

Note Also: This will fail (i.e. throw an `IndexOutOfRangeException`) if your input is not in the expected format. If you want to validate some dodgy input then a Regex *is* probably what you want - other @Rich's answer looks good to me.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The above works well. My only issue is I'm reading the delimited string from the cookie and just wanted to make sure user is not changing it before I read it. Anyhow @kol gave me exact regex below.

Comment: Yes, if you need to validate that some input matches your format then regex is the right tool.

Answer (score 1):

I am not really sure if I understand how your format works, but if everything must have an ID and volume int the format [id],[volume];[id],[volume]; then i would say use a regex like:

```
(([0-9]),([0-9]);)+
```

but your example of `1,3;5,1;6;4` does not seem to follow that format, so if you want the volume to be optional then:

```
(([0-9])(,[0-9])?;)+
```

should work.  If you want to try out regex patterns then I would suggest using an online utility such as http://regexpal.com